# In Dask, can tensors be reshaped to 2D matrices in Dask without precomputing the size?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dask

While trying to create a python base class capable of vectorizing scalar functions on Dask, I encountered a problem reshaping tensors to 2D matrices.  Solving this issue would facilitate the  creation of sklearn pipelines that operate interchangeably on Numpy, Pandas and Dask datatypes.

The following code works on Dask **0.18.2** but fails on Dask **0.19.4** and **0.20.0**:

```
import dask
import dask.array
import dask.dataframe
import numpy
import pandas

def and1(x): return numpy.array([x, x+1], dtype=numpy.float32)

expected = numpy.array([[10, 11, 20, 21], 
                        [30, 31, 40, 41]], 
                       dtype=numpy.float32)

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict({
  'c1': [10, 30], 'c2': [20, 40]
})

ddf = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

# Dask generalized universal function that outputs 2 values per input value
guf = dask.array.gufunc(
    pyfunc=and1,
    signature='()->(n)',
    output_dtypes=numpy.float32,
    output_sizes={'n': 2},
    vectorize=True,
    allow_rechunk = False
)

da = guf(ddf)
da_reshaped = da.reshape((-1, numpy.prod(da.shape[1:])))
npa = da_reshaped.compute()

assert da.shape == (2, 2, 2)  # (input rows, input cols, outputs per cols)
numpy.testing.assert_array_equal(expected, npa)
```

In Dask 0.19.4 and 0.20.0 `reshape` raises a ValueError since the first element of `da`s shape is `NaN` (see the stack trace for details).

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-847-ad2c41e1d88c> in <module>
     24 
     25 da = guf(ddf)
---> 26 da_r = da.reshape((-1, numpy.prod(da.shape[1:])))
     27 npa = da_r.compute()
     28 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/array/core.py in reshape(self, *shape)
   1398         if len(shape) == 1 and not isinstance(shape[0], Number):
   1399             shape = shape[0]
-> 1400         return reshape(self, shape)
   1401 
   1402     def topk(self, k, axis=-1, split_every=None):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/array/reshape.py in reshape(x, shape)
    160         if len(shape) == 1 and x.ndim == 1:
    161             return x
--> 162         missing_size = sanitize_index(x.size / reduce(mul, known_sizes, 1))
    163         shape = tuple(missing_size if s == -1 else s for s in shape)
    164 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/array/slicing.py in sanitize_index(ind)
     58                      _sanitize_index_element(ind.step))
     59     elif isinstance(ind, Number):
---> 60         return _sanitize_index_element(ind)
     61     elif is_dask_collection(ind):
     62         return ind

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/array/slicing.py in _sanitize_index_element(ind)
     20     """Sanitize a one-element index."""
     21     if isinstance(ind, Number):
---> 22         ind2 = int(ind)
     23         if ind2 != ind:
     24             raise IndexError("Bad index.  Must be integer-like: %s" % ind)

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

**Is there another way to reshape Dask Arrays in Dask 0.20.0+ without precomputing the size?**
**If so, is the reshaping a constant time operation as it appears to be in Numpy?**

I want to create a matrix (shape = (R, C)) such that the first axis is not changed but all subsequent axes are merged in `"C"` order (the default in both Dask and Numpy).

(BTW, I already saw: [Reshape a dask array (obtained from a dask dataframe column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52212827/reshape-a-dask-array-obtained-from-a-dask-dataframe-column))